# The way to pass input for azure machine experiment from app ( for example console app )

Tags: azure, prediction, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to do some kind of web job application that can run for period time and make prediction on azure machine learning studio. After that i want get the result of this experiment and do something with that in my console application. What is the best way to do this in azure with machine learning or maybe some similiar stuff to prediction data from data series ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using Azure Data Factory to create a Machine Learning pipeline or use Azure ML Studio's Predictive Web Services.

1. With Azure Data Factory
   Follow [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-azure-ml-batch-execution-activity) for details. Azure Data Factory implementations would seem difficult at first but they do work great with Azure ML experiments.

   Azure Data Factory can run your ML Experiment on a schedule or one-off at a specified time (I guess you can set only for UTC Timezone right now) and monitor it through a dashboard (which is pretty cool).

   As an example you can look @ [ML Batch Execution](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/data-factory/data-factory-azure-ml-batch-execution-activity.md). I used this in one of our implementations (we do have latency issues, but trying to solve that).
2. If you directly want to use the experiment in your console (assuming it is a web application), use create a Predictive Web service out of your ML Experiment, details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-walkthrough-5-publish-web-service)

I couldn't exactly understand your use case so I posted two alternatives that should help you. Hope this might lead you to a better solution/approach.